# Multiple Record on single line in xcode

Tags: ios, uitableview, gridview

how to show 4 records in custome cell that is fetched from the managed object context, or core data. also i want this to be displayed in grid view style. thanks in advance

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i have tried every gridview like ag, dt and so on. but neither of them work correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Why not have 4 arrays that get data from whatever source you want (Core Data, etc).  Then, so long as the arrays are the same length - these can be used to have 4 distinct values in each cell.

As far as a true "Grid View" layout, check out [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).  Haven't used it, but have heard lots of good things about it.

Comment: but AQGridView does not have didselectrow at indexpath .. so how i can gain this function

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used it.  I am sure it has something similar.  Why not go with a standard tableview and take the lines out and use 4 distinct data sources?

Comment: i am new to ios. so if u plz help me out here. i don't know how to do this. like creating 4 different data source.